# How to create short uuid with Django

Tags: python, django, uuid

I have a model and UUID as primary key field. UUID id is way too long. I'd like to have it short similar to YouTube.

```
class Video(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, 
        default=uuid.uuid4, 
        editable=False,
    )
```

Instead of this

```
UUID('b39596dd-10c9-42c9-91ee-9e45b78ce3c1')
```

I want to have just this

```
UUID('b39596dd')
```

How can I achieve above?

Comment: why not use a CharField and create the uuid pk manaully for that field?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki seems too much work, how would I do that?

Comment: To be clear, OP is asking for a compact representation of the UUID. He/she is not asking for a UUID that is stored in fewer bits.

Answer (score 5):

A bit old question, but [shortuuidfield](https://github.com/benrobster/django-shortuuidfield) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [shortuuid](https://github.com/skorokithakis/shortuuid) library:

```
from shortuuid.django_fields import ShortUUIDField
id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, length=11, max_length=11)
```

But you should pay attention to this issue. The smaller the size of the UUID, the higher the probability of Collision.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the `uuid` is defined as the `time_low` so we can do this, however it will no longer be a `uuid.UUID` type.

```
sample = uuid.uuid4()

UUID('6af2fd74-fbaf-4a9a-a973-8d052634a624')

tl = sample.time_low

1794309492L
```

Then we just convert it back to hex,

```
hex(int(tl.time_low))[2:]

'6af2fd74'
```

You can do the same thing with just splitting it as a normal string but I don't see why it matters. Once you assign this to a variable it's a given so you can parse it as you choose.

Comment: how unique is it though? At what point it could cause an issue?